# Difficulty Accessing Values from JSON Object Using PHP- Sunlight Labs congressapi

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to pull values from a JSON object pulled from the Sunlight Labs Congress API using PHP. I'm able to get request response data into a JSON object, but haven't had any success getting specific values out of the object. I can successfully dump the object using print_r.

I've been experimenting with PHP for about 12 hours now, so this is a totally n00b question...

Here's the PHP:

```
$zip = $_REQUEST['zip'];
$sf = new SunlightLegislator;

$data = $sf->legislatorZipCode( $zip );
$leg = json_decode($data);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data).'</pre><p>';
echo 'First Name ';

echo $leg[1]->legislator->firstname;

echo $leg[1]->firstname;
?>
```

The PHP yields this output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [legislator] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [website] => http://bass.house.gov/
                    [fax] => 202-225-2946
                    [govtrack_id] => 400019
                    [firstname] => Charles
                    [chamber] => house
                    [middlename] => 
                    [lastname] => Bass
                    [congress_office] => 2350 Rayburn House Office Building
                    [eventful_id] => 
                    [phone] => 202-225-5206
                    [webform] => 
                    [youtube_url] => 
                    [nickname] => Charlie
                    [gender] => M
                    [district] => 2
                    [title] => Rep
                    [congresspedia_url] => 
                    [in_office] => 1
                    [senate_class] => 
                    [name_suffix] => 
                    [twitter_id] => RepCharlesBass
                    [birthdate] => 1952-01-08
                    [bioguide_id] => B000220
                    [fec_id] => H0NH02017
                    [state] => NH
                    [crp_id] => N00000423
                    [official_rss] => 
                    [facebook_id] => 
                    [party] => R
                    [email] => 
                    [votesmart_id] => 22216
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [legislator] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [website] => http://shaheen.senate.gov
                    [fax] => 
                    [govtrack_id] => 412323

                    ...SNIPPAGE...

                    [facebook_id] => SenatorShaheen
                    [party] => D
                    [email] => 
                    [votesmart_id] => 1663
                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [legislator] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [website] => http://ayotte.senate.gov 
                    [fax] => 
                    [govtrack_id] => 412493
                    [firstname] => Kelly
                    [chamber] => senate
                    [middlename] => A 

                    ...SNIPPAGE...

                    [email] => 
                    [votesmart_id] => 42352
                )

        )

)
First Name
```

At the moment, I'm just trying to output the first legislator's first name to the page. I'm certain that the data's there, and doing an error check on `json_decode` yields no errors. I think my trouble is in the syntax I'm using to access the decoded object.

The questions:
How would I output the a legislator's first name? 
Is it possible that the `website` field is breaking object access?

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: After getting a little deeper with some of the debugging functionality of PHP, it appears that my problem is that I'm handing json_decode and object rather than a string.

I've modified the php according to information found in another post here, adding 
`ini_set('display_errors',1);`
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

yields a new error/warning: 
`json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given ...`

So, I was probably barking up the wrong tree with my attempts to access the array data. Instead I have to convert the returned object to an array first.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be solved on [stdClass Object problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567698/stdclass-object-problems) by @soulmerge. For your object, the following would work:

```
$array = (array) $result;
$array[0]->legislator->website;
```