# Echo values in nested array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm passing an array of data from AngularJS to PHP, and I end up with the following array:

```
if(in_array('application/json', $contentType)) { // Check if Content-Type is JSON
  $data = json_decode($rawBody); // Then decode it
  $productes = $data->products;
} else {
  parse_str($data, $data); // If not JSON, just do same as PHP default method
}

products:[
  0:{
    product: "Name1",
    number: 1
  },
  1:{
    product: "Name2",
    number: 3
  }    
]
```

How could I manage to loop through it to end up displaying a list of products like so:

```
<li>Name1 (1)</li>
<li>Name2 (3)</li>
```

I've tried the following but no luck:

```
foreach ($products as $value) {
    echo "<li>". $value->product ." (". $value->number .")</li>";
}
```

This is what I get when I do var_dump($products):

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["product"]=>
    string(19) "Croissant d'ametlla"
    ["number"]=>
    int(1)
    ["preu"]=>
    float(1.95)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["product"]=>
    string(29) "Pain au chocolat (napolitana)"
    ["number"]=>
    int(1)
    ["preu"]=>
    float(1.4)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
    ["product"]=>
    string(16) "Brioche de sucre"
    ["number"]=>
    int(1)
    ["preu"]=>
    float(1.2)
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
    ["product"]=>
    string(36) "Pa de blat egipci i integral (Xusco)"
    ["number"]=>
    int(1)
    ["preu"]=>
    float(4.45)
  }
}
```

## SOLUTION

As I was already intially decoding the JSON, this is what ended up working:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
  echo "<li>". $product->product ." (". $product->number .")</li>";
};
```

Comment: please try to `var_dump($products)` and share the result

Comment: @Mohammad see edit : )

Comment: When you say "...but no luck", what output did you get? Was there an error? Did anything show at all?

Comment: @EricMitjans please have a look on this answer [stdClass Object problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1567864/2101939)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$json = '{"products":[{"product":"Name1","number":1},{"product":"Name2","number":3}]}';
$products = json_decode($json, TRUE)["products"];
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo "<li>{$product["product"]} ({$product["number"]})</li>";
}
```

You can try it here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/53394eb416be1727398f02e8a0adac68a5ce424e

Answer (score 4):

As it's an array, give the following a try:

```
foreach ($products as $value) {
    echo "<li>". $value['product'] ." (". $value['number'] .")</li>";
}
```